# Launch custom Android application from browser and URL shortener

Tags: android, intentfilter, url-shortener

I know that if I add an intent-filter to my AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.example.com"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

The user will be promoted to use my app if he clicks on a site with the www.example.com host. But this doesn't seem to work if the link gets redirected by an url shortener service. How is Youtube able to handle url-shortened URLs when the link get's redirected by such service?

Comment: did you add category browsable to your intent filter ?

Comment: I did. I will edit my question.